# Can't Edit Row Layout on SiteOrigin Plugin

Tags: plugins

I am trying to edit the layout of every row in my homepage using Siteorigin PLug-in. but Everyrtime I Edit and save, it will go back to the default set-up. I cannot even upload background image on my row. i cannot click the upload button. please help. thanks

Comment: I don't know the SiteOrigin plugin, but are you saying it's the SiteOrigin functionality that isn't working? You should probably report this to the SiteOrigin authors.

Comment: I did send them an email. but didn't reply on my last message. i tried to deactivate all my plugins, but nothing happened. hope someone can help me